# Number decomposer doesn't work well with loop. What is the reason?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, operator-keyword

Edit: ITS SOLVED! It was the '/' operator, when all of them were substituted by '//' operators everything worked!
I made a thing that is supposed to decompose numbers into the first 5 prime numbers, but when I put a big number on it, it just stops midway.

```
x = int(input('Number to decompose:'))
while((x % 2)== 0):
    x = int(x / 2)
    print(x, '2')
while((x % 2)== 0):
    x = int(x / 2)
    print(x, '2')
while((x % 5)== 0):
    x = int(x / 5)
    print(x, '5')
while((x % 7)== 0):
    x = int(x / 7)
    print(x, '7')
while((x % 11)== 0):
    x = int(x / 11)
    print(x, '11')
```

If I introduce a little number such as 33578167194000 it decomsposes down to 13, but if put 547945845108645662650548617216 it stops midways in this number

`Number to decompose:547945845108645662650548617216
273972922554322831325274308608 2
136986461277161415662637154304 2
68493230638580707831318577152 2
34246615319290353915659288576 2
17123307659645176957829644288 2
8561653829822588478914822144 2
4280826914911294239457411072 2
2140413457455647119728705536 2
1070206728727823559864352768 2
535103364363911779932176384 2
267551682181955889966088192 2
133775841090977944983044096 2
66887920545488972491522048 2
33443960272744486245761024 2
16721980136372243122880512 2
8360990068186121561440256 2
4180495034093060780720128 2
2090247517046530390360064 2
1045123758523265195180032 2
522561879261632597590016 2
261280939630816298795008 2
130640469815408149397504 2
65320234907704074698752 2
32660117453852037349376 2
16330058726926018674688 2
8165029363463009337344 2
4082514681731504668672 2
2041257340865752334336 2
1020628670432876167168 2
510314335216438083584 2
255157167608219041792 2
127578583804109520896 2
63789291902054760448 2
31894645951027380224 2
15947322975513690112 2
7973661487756845056 2
3986830743878422528 2
1993415371939211264 2
996707685969605632 2
498353842984802816 2
249176921492401408 2
124588460746200704 2
62294230373100352 2
31147115186550176 2
15573557593275088 2
7786778796637544 2
3893389398318772 2
1946694699159386 2
973347349579693 2
88486122689063 11
8044192971733 11`
And just stops. Changing the number of zeros or the number also changes the number of times that the number is divided, even if it does not finish the decomposition
Edit: The number is not composed of those numbers, but should be-> The number was generated by:

```
y = int(random.randrange(0, 20))
print((y))
z = int(random.randrange(0, 20))
print(z)
c = int(random.randrange(0, 20))
print(c)
v = int(random.randrange(0, 20))
print(v)
j = int(random.randrange(0, 20))
print(j)
e = int(b*((2**y)*(3**z)*(5**c)*(7**v)*(11**j)))
for n in (0, 500):
    if (e % 10) == 0:
     e = int(e / 10)
    else:
     break
print (int(e), n)
```

where b is 13
Where in all this there is a mistake that is not throwing the 13 at the decomposing?
Thanks for the patience

Comment: Your math is wrong. The numbers you used to test the algorithm have [prime factorizations containing primes much larger than 11](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=547945845108645662650548617216+prime+factorization). Not like hardcoding all the small primes is the proper way to factor a number. Instead, just use a loop to count up from 2 to the square root of the input number, and for each potential factor, divide the big number until it's no longer divisible. Search up "prime factorization algorithm".

Comment: Instead of e.g. `int(x / 2)`, you should use `x // 2`. In Python 3, `x / 2` returns a `float`, which does not have arbitrary precision, screwing with the math!